# how to pass the values of set of input boxes of key value pair to the parent scope in angular js

Tags: angularjs, key-value

I have created a directive which contains a map of key value pairs. In edit mode i used to populate the values of entries using ng-repeat, Also a user can add more key value pairs when he press a add button

Below is the code

```
angular.module('key_value_component',
[])
.directive('keyValuePairs', function ($compile, $templateCache) {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'key_value.tpl.html',
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            entries: "=ngModel"
        },
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.create_key_value = function () {
                $scope.$broadcast('ready-to-render');
            }
        }
    };
})


.directive("keyValueInit", function ($compile, $templateCache) {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'key_value_init.tpl.html',
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
            scope.$on('ready-to-render', function (event) {
                list_select = $compile($templateCache.get("key_value_input.tpl.html"))(scope);
                element.parents('.key_value_element').append(list_select);
            })
        }
    }
}).directive("keyValue", function ($compile, $templateCache) {
return {
    templateUrl: 'key_value_input.tpl.html',
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
}});
```

templates :
key_value_tpl.html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="key_value_header">
<button class="btn btn-success btn-add pull-right" type="button" ng-click="create_key_value()">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
</button>
<div class="col-sm-4"><strong>key</strong></div>
<div class="col-sm-4"><strong>value</strong></div>
</div>
<div class="key_value_body">
    <key-value ng-repeat="(key,value) in entries"></key-value>
    <div class="key_value_element">
        <key-value-init></key-value-init>
    </div>
</div>
```

key_value_input.tpl.html

```
<div class="form-group key_value">
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <input  class="form-control key_value_key" type="text" ng-value="key" ng-readonly="key"/>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <input  class="form-control key_value_value" type="text"  ng-value="value" ng-readonly="value"/>
</div>
<input-remove-button></input-remove-button>
```

key_value_init.tpl.html

`<div></div>`

If someone add a new key value pair I want to append its value in entries. A submit event is happening outside the directive in the form. the directive is part of that form.